# how to translate user roles created with bitmask

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i was doing something similar to [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association?view=asciicast) example, shown in RailsCast

It works fine, but i want those roles to be translated in the form. where in locales can I set this? I mean those are not real attributes, just elements of the defined array

Answer (score 0):

Edit `config/locales/en.yml` or whatever language you want.

```
en:
  roles:
    admin: 'Super Admin'
    moderator: 'Editor'
    author: 'Owner'
```

Then in in your form:

```
<%= check_box_tag "user[roles][]", t("roles.#{role}"), @user.roles.include?(role) %>
```

Comment: what to do with t("roles.#{role}") in simple_form?

Comment: Quick and dirty `f.collection_check_boxes :roles, [[1, t('roles.admin')], [2, t('roles.moderator')], [4, t('roles.author')]], :first, :last`

Comment: actually i did smth like this     = f.input :roles, as: :check_boxes, collection: User::ROLES

Comment: But you asked something different: You asked this 'roles to be translated in the form' How did you translated User::ROLES?

Comment: then to be specific: my input is = f.input :roles, as: :check_boxes, collection: User::ROLES, how do i set simple_form.pl.yml to have ROLES translated?